# How to populate second combo depending on first combo value from json response in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch-2, extjs4.1, sencha-architect

I am trying to populate a second combo depending on the first combo from json response like displaying subcategory value in second combo using category value in first combo. All my values are coming from json array response, I am trying to set root property dynamically and load the store of second combo box in controller in first combo change function but it's not populating the data. Can anybody tell me what the problem is. How do I fix it? I have posted my code below for the change function of first combo:

```
valueChange:function(combo, ewVal, oldVal,optionsVal) {
    for(var i=0;i<tempstore.getCount();i++){
          var record = tempstore.getAt(i);

//checking for user selection id  with store id 
 if(record.get('categoryId')==ewVal)         
 {
   value="category.category1.category["+i+"].subCategory.subCategory1";
tempsecondCompostore.getProxy().getReader().setRootProperty(value);    
tempsecondCompostore.load();
cmbSecond.setStore(tempsecondCompostore);

mdSecond.setDisplayField('subCategoryName');
cmdSecond.setValueField('subCategoryId');
 break;
       }
      }
```

This is my Second combo Model:

```
Ext.define('Test.model.SubCategoryModel', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
     {
      name:'subCategoryName',
      type:'string'

     },
     {
      name:'subCategoryId',
      type:'string'
     }


    ]

});
```

This is my Second Combo store:

```
Ext.define('Test.store.SubCategoryStore', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Store',
    storeId : 'secondcombo',
    model : 'Test.model.SubCategoryModel',
    //autoLoad : 'true',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        url : 'data.json',
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            rootProperty:'category.category1.category[0].subCategory.subCategory1
        }
    }
```

});

In View Displaying combo:

```
xtype: 'fieldset',
            width:400,
            heigth:200,
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'selectfield',
                    label: 'Select',
                    store : 'secondcombo',
                    width:400,
                    heigth:200,
                    queryMode: 'local',
                    displayField :'subCategoryName',
                    valueField :'subCategoryId',
                    id:'cmbSecond'




                }
            ]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the load() of the store is asynchronous and you need to include the lines after this call in the callback.